# Trying to split string in google sheets that have more than one space

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to split the text in column A based on if the text contains more than one space. When I run it in the script editor, nothing runs. I'm not sure what I need to fix.

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
var re = new RegExp("/  +/")
function rename() {
  for(n=0;n<values.length;++n){
    var cell = values[n][0] ;
    var result = cell.split(re);
  }
}

rename();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting) to learn about how to troubleshoot your scripts on Google Apps Scripts.

Regarding your code, below I added it with slight changes described with inline comments.

---

Note: Test this on sheets with a small data range.

---

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
var re = new RegExp("  +"); // Slashes removed
function rename() {
  for(n=0;n<values.length;n++){ // plus sign moved after n
    var cell = values[n][0] ;
    var result = cell.split(re);
    Logger.log(result); // This line will write the result text to the debugging logs.
  }
}

// rename(); this line should not be included.
```

Comment: That was pretty helpful. Much apreicated